# Open Certain Keyboard Android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I've noticed that some apps when you click on something like edittext has a carriage return while others have a next button in place of a carriage return. I think the carriage return in the default so I'm wondering how you change it to a next button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more **edittext** fields on a layout and want to replace the carriage return with a next button you can change the IME options in the layout xml:

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionNext" ....></EditText>
```

This will change the focus to the next edittext field.

Read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to set single line property to EditText